# what's the best way to execute fast aggregation queries based on YEAR and MONTH filters in addition to dynamic filters

Tags: mysql, indexing, relational-database, analytics, partitioning

My SQL table is going to have millions of rows. Currently, with only 2M rows, my aggregation queries take anywhere between 20 seconds to a minute.

The filters in `WHERE` clause for aggregation queries are going to be based on user-selected values of filters from different combinations of those filters.

I intend to make a selection of "YEAR" and "MONTH" filter  mandatory which should narrow down the number of rows to get the aggregates on. However, it does not seem to be making much of a difference with `YEAR` and `Month` filter .

For ex:

```
select importer_name
     , ROUND(SUM(total_value_usd_exchange), 2) AS top15_usd
  from importer_bills
 WHERE bill_of_entry_year = 2020
   AND bill_of_entry_month = 3
   AND 
...ANY COMBINATION OF USER SELECTED FILTERS
 group
    by importer_name
 order  
    by ROUND(SUM(total_value_usd_exchange), 2) desc 
 limit 15 offset 0;
```

I tried to partition data by YEAR as well but that did not help either. Since users may or may not select filters from the other 7 filterable columns, It's unnecessary to create complex indexes. I have already created simple indexes on those columns that data can be filtered on. What can be done to have a reasonable speed of aggregation queries here?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You could include the query execution plan too. By the way, what is the datatype for you year and month field?

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeatedly aggregrate.  Build and maintain a Summary Table.  The updating of such may take seconds instead of minutes.

Have one row in the aggregation table for each day.  From that you can further `SUM()` to get a week's or month's total.  (Or any number of days.)

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables